# SharPoint 2013: How to find the time elapsed of an item/document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I want to implement a functionality in which I would like to show the time elpased in this format:

**16 hours ago**.. or **4 days ago**

[image]

Is there any method exist in Sharepoint CSOM to perform this operation

Comment: Why don't you count from the latest modified date? I think that would be the way MS does it.

Comment: Could you please provide some pointers or some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time) resolved my problem.

I have used the jquery plugin **jquery.timeago**. You can download it from [here](http://timeago.yarp.com/)